# Evens & odds functions symbolism

Tags: functions

Just a simple question! Is there any symbol for a add or even function, like the symbol of an increasing function? If there isn't any symbol how can I express in a short an even or an odd function?

Comment: What's the symbol for an increasing function?

Answer (score 1):

The closest to a *symbol* I can think is this,

### Odd Function

$$
f(x) = -f(-x)
$$

### Even Function

$$
f(x)=f(-x)
$$

for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: What about $\frac{1}{x}$ ? I would consider it to be odd. But the equation does not hold for $x=0$ because the function is not defined there.

Comment: You can change "$x \in \mathbb R$" to "all $x$ in the domain of $f$".

Answer (score 1):

A short definition of even/odd functions :

$f(x)$ is $\color\green {even}(\color\red {odd})$ if and only if $\color\green {f(-x)=f(x)}$ ($\color\red {f(-x)=-f(x)}$) holds for every $x\in \mathbb D$ and $f(-x)$ is defined if and only if $f(x)$ is defined

Comment: Whoa, that was simultaneous!

Comment: I am not sure whether an even/odd function has to be defined everywhere. But I think $\frac{1}{x}$, for example, is considered to be odd.